# I dont know if i should use models.Foreignkey or just Charfield to store oauth token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, mysql-python

I need to store the username and twitter token when he/she logs in and then later use it for whatever purpose, should i use FK for the twiter token field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well FK is used in 1:n so if the token can be used for multiple users, then you can use it ...

if the token is unique for user (in this example i think it is) you can use classic Charfield on user model... and you will avoid join tables every time you want to get users token.